# Module for converting number to month name in perl

Tags: perl

My XML date input is : 2012-12-21 i.e. YYYY-MM-DD format.
I want to convert month number into month name. i.e. 2012-Dec-21
Can anyone suggest which perl module is useful & how to use it with an example since I am very new to perl.

Comment: I tried with usual hash menthod. But I want to do this in a single step so need help about perl module.

Comment: Of course you could create an array of `@month` and retrieve value from `MM-1`...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use core perl's [`Time::Piece`](https://metacpan.org/module/Time%253A%253APiece):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use 5.10;
use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Piece;

my $date = '2012-12-21';
# strftime format - http://www.unix.com/man-page/FreeBSD/3/strftime/
my $t = Time::Piece->strptime($date, '%Y-%m-%d');
say $t->month;                # Dec
say $t->strftime('%Y-%b-%d'); # 2012-Dec-21
```

Comment: Similar result could be accomplished using `POSIX::strftime` but then each part of the date should be extracted with regex, `split` or similar function, plus the operations of substracting `1` to the month and `1900` to the year. I like this one, **+1**

Answer (score 3):

```
use strict;

my $date='2012-12-21';

my %mons = ("01"=>'Jan',"02"=>'Feb',"03"=>'Mar',"04"=>'Apr',"05"=>'May',"06"=>'Jun',"07"=>'Jul',"08"=>'Aug',"09"=>'Sep',"10"=>'Oct',"11"=>'Nov',"12"=>'Dec');

$date=~s/(\d{4})\-(\d{2})\-(\d{2})/my $year=$1; my $month=$2; my $day=$3; "$year-$mons{$month}-$day"/egs;

print $date;
```